# How to keep out of viewport leaflet polylines rendered at all times?

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, polyline

Whenever I move the view on my leaflet map, polylines whose centers are no longer in view are removed. I have a polyline with a large stroke size (~500px) that is not visible even when part of it should be. This same problem can also be observed when dragging the map, polylines are not redrawn until the drag ends. Example shown below.

[image: The left part of the polylines is not drawn until the drag ends]

I have tried adding a listener for the leaflet `remove` event but that is not triggering. I also tried overriding the `onRemove` method for the polyline but that did not work. For now to get around this I have made the map bigger than the screen, but that causes some slowdown.

I assume it is a performance feature to remove non-visible polylines from the map. Does anyone know if that this can be disabled?

Comment: It's really cute to call that a feature, but it's definitely not SVG's "fault"

Comment: So it's leaflet's fault?

Comment: Probably, by way of deduction (*might* be your fault as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set `L.Path.CLIP_PADDING`.

Found by looking through closed issues on the github repo. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2814.

Also in the docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-clip_padding

"How much to extend the clip area around the map view (relative to its size, e.g. 0.5 is half the screen in each direction). Smaller values mean that you will see clipped ends of paths while you're dragging the map, and bigger values decrease drawing performance."

Answer (score 3):

yes, as you said the polylines, geoJSON will only redraw after receiving the "**dragend**" event, so we must redraw even during the drag and we can easily make it happen by writing the following code

```
map.on('drag', () => {
  map.fitBounds(map.getBounds());
});
```

even `L.Path.CLIP_PADDING` didn't work for me. but forcefully setting the bounds worked for me.
also, see the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ovhnfcud/49/).